# Cloudwatch logs streaming to ElasticSearch AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So, I created the cloudwatch index and streaming the cloud watch logs to elastic search and I am seeing data, however, I am only seeing current date data. I dont see old logs in elastic search which are in same log group in cloudwatch. I changed the date filter in elastic search, but dont see any change. Any idea why?

The index name created is, **cwl-2018.03.20**

Comment: I am facing an issue in streaming cloudwatch log groups to Amazon elastic search service. On selecting the Amazon ES cluster, it just keeps on processing for an indefinite duration.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. The streaming of logs from CloudWatch to Elasticsearch relies of a feature called [subscription filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutSubscriptionFilter.html) which only forwards new data to the destination.